# Abbott; Understanding Analysis; Exercise 1.3.4 Proof Check

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Looking for suggestions and verification on this proof.

The exercise reads as follows:
*Assume that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, bounded above, and satisfy $B \subseteq A$. Show $sup B \leq sup A$.*

And this is my proof!
**Proof:**
Say $B = A$. Then $supB=supA$, so certainly $supB \leq supA$.
Say $B$ is a proper subset of $A$. Assume $supB > supA$. Take some element $x = \frac{supB+supA}{2}$. Then since $supB > supA, x \in B$ and $x \not\in A$, since $\frac{supB+supA}{2} > supA$ since $supB > supA$. But then $B \not\subseteq A$ and $B \subseteq A$, which is a contradiction. So the assumption is false.

Something about my proof doesn't feel right, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: You don't necessarily have $x \in B$. $x \leq supB$ doesn't imply $x \in B$.

Answer (score 1):

*Supremum definition*

$\sup(B)$ is the smallest M such that $\forall x\in B, \ x\leq M \tag 1$

*Proof*

$\forall x \in B, $ we have   $x\in A $ therefore $x\leq \sup(A)$

So $\sup(A)$ is such a M from equation $(1)$ and $\sup(B)$ is the smallest therefore: $$\sup(B)\leq \sup(A) \tag 2$$

*About your proof*

The only issue with your proof I see is assuming $x = \dfrac{\sup(A) + \sup(B)}{2}$ belongs to B even thought the intuition is there this is not true.

What you can be certain which follows the same logic is that $ \exists x\in B$ s.t $\sup A<x \leq \sup B$ because of the definition of $\sup(B)$ and $\sup(A) <\sup(B)$. So that $x\in B$ and $x\notin A$ and your proof would work. 
But again the key property that leads to the existence of such a x you want to prove is the minimality of the supremum.

Comment: He still can say $x \notin A$ since $x > supA$.

Comment: @AntoineGiard ah yes you are right. And actually he could find a $x\in B$ s.t $\sup A<x \leq \sup B$ because of the definition of sup. So that $x\in B$ and $x\notin A$ and his proof would work.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That was it! Thanks a lot. That was the key I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

The number $\sigma:=\sup A$ is an upper bound of $A$. Since $B\subset A$ this number $\sigma$ is an upper bound of $B$ as well. It follows that $\sup B\leq \sigma$.